# NSAttributedString initWithData makes my screen flickers in after IOS 9

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

After a long research, I found that initWithData method of NSAttributedString flickers my screen. It's very strange. It never happened before IOS 9. Here's my code:

```
NSString *const str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: %@; color:%@; font-size:%@\";>%@</span>", fontFace, _shop.currentTheme.options.itemDetailTextColor, fontSize,[entity description]];
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};

//Screen flickers after the code below
NSAttributedString *const text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
itemDescriptionLabel.text = @"text"; //text;
```

Where am I wrong?

UPDATE:

If I remove NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType from options, it works fine.

Comment: Where is this code? If you create an simple single view iOS app with only the above code, do you still see the problem?

Comment: If I set the options to nil, app works fine. Problem is about options I guess.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: This code is in a view controller's viewDidLoad method. I didn't try with a single view app. Because I am now sure it is because of NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType option

Comment: @Burak: Are you using `label.attributedText` when you set `text` instead of `@"text"`?

Comment: yes, I was using attributedTExt. I totally moved to DTCoreText with TTTAttributedLabel and now it works fine.